# Jupyter ImportError after installing IJavascript

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ijavascript

My Jupyter has stopped working after I installed the Ijavascript. I have tried everything I could but couldn't correct the issue.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: The specified module could not be found.
[I 10:22:03.045 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports

It's trying to restart the Kernel repeatedly but failing.